# What's the meaning of this piece of code?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(requestAddressUpdatedNotification:) 
                                             name:MTAddressUpdatedNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Can anyone tell me what will happen if I write this piece of code in my program ?

And when will the method `requestAddressUpdatedNotification` be called?

Comment: You might like to have a look at [the Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 4):

The code informs the default `NSNotificationCenter` to notify your object (`self`) when a `MTAddressUpdatedNotification NSNotification` occurs and to trigger `requestAddressUpdatedNotification:` method which must be defined (within `@implementation…@end`) in the same class.

Comment: So you mean if MTAddressUpdatedNotification occurs and requestAddressUpdatedNotification will be called?

Comment: Yes, when a MTAddressUpdatedNotification is posted, your requestAddressUpdatedNotification: will be triggered or in Objective-C parlance "receive a message".